# C++ OOP inventory and item class

Tags: c++, class, inventory

creating Inventory class as well as item class... working on inventory "removing" item from inventory.

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>

void Inventory::PrintInventory() {
    for (auto i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << i->name << " " << i->numItem << std::endl;
    }
}

void Inventory::ReceiveItem(Item item) {
    items.push_back(item);
}

Item Inventory::TakeItem(int num) {
    items.erase(items.begin() + num);
    auto item = std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), num);
    //issue is here
    //my teacher said to set it up as Item Inventory that takes in an int.
    return item;
}
```

//this is in the actor class...

```
void Actor::GiveItem(Actor* actor, Item item) {
    int num = item.numItem;
    actor->inventory.ReceiveItem(item);
    inventory.TakeItem(num);
}
```

question is... im not sure what to do in the Item Inventory function of the Inventory class, it's supposed to return something, but im not sure why.. teacher is unreachable. and if it is supposed to return an Item object, i need to get Item object from the integer value. the Item objects class has  a char* name; and int numItem;

Comment: I don't see any actual question here.

Comment: clarified the question.

Comment: my guess is that Item is the indexing function(analogous to [] operator) that returns the item at slot specified either 0 or 1 indexed depending on your specification.

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know how you expect to find and return an item in the list **after** erasing it.

Comment: if there is a better way to write it, then please help a brother out. i agree that it would be dumb to return a value that were going to delete. that's why i'm confused on the return part as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is supposed to return an `Item` object, I need to get `Item` object from the integer value.

Okay so you're pretty close here.  From your description it sounds like `Item` is defined as

```
struct Item
{
    std::string name;
    int numItem;  ///< search for this value
};
```

And your `items` is an STL container of `Item`, we'll use `std::vector<Item> items;`.

If you must return an `Item` object then you should declare a default `Item` to return on error. If you successfully find a match for `Item::numItem` then you will populate your default `Item` with these values. Finally, if you did find an item to take, you will erase it for inventory housekeeping. Do not erase the `Item` before you find it for obvious reasons!

```
Item TakeItem(int num)
{
    Item localItem;
    for (auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end();) {
        // if we find a match set local item and then
        // remove the item from inventory
        // and break out of loop since we are done
        if ((*it).numItem == num) {
            localItem = *it;
            it = items.erase(it);
            break; // found and removed from inventory!
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return localItem;
}
```

It's a little bit awkward to return a default-constructed `Item` in the event that there were not any matches for `num` found, but if you want to detect that case you could always do something like initialize it to "bogus" values that you know can't be in your inventory.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd move the `++it` into the for loop because A) it's less surprising there B) the loop exits when the erase takes place so you don't have to worry about `++it` on a dead iterator.